# When I am Uploading an Image in WordPress Via media, The image is not showing

Tags: wordpress

When I upload an image by WordPress media the image is not shown in the media list.Wordpress version 4.7.7
https://prnt.sc/h7m9d6

Comment: can you specily the image Format

Comment: Image format is .jpg

Comment: can you share the image at any image sharing site

Comment: I think your image is currupted. to check this open your image in browser,weather it is showing or not

Comment: Can you please check the directory permissions of "Uploads" directory...may be the case due to that you're facing such issues..

Answer (score 0):

can you please check the image is uploaded by you is reflect in your 
**wp-content/uploads**  folder or not.

if not then upload image via FTP and then check.

May be this will be help you to solve your question.

for any query feel free to ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the permissions of your uploads folder to 775 using an FTP client, such as Filezilla.

[Changing File Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Hope this helps.